# Package ‘RPostgreSQL’ is not available (for R version 2.13.1)?

Tags: r, postgresql

I'm trying to install the "RPostgreSQL" package (using R 2.13.1, Mac OS X Snow Leopard).

When I run `install.packages("RPostgreSQL")`, I get this error:

```
In getDependencies(pkgs, dependencies, available, lib) :
  package ‘RPostgreSQL’ is not available (for R version 2.13.1)
```

So I tried downloading from source, and running `r CMD INSTALL RPostgreSQL_0.1-7.tar.gz`, and it seemed to install fine, but when I call `library(RPostgreSQL)`, I get this error:

```
`Error: package 'RPostgreSQL' is not installed for 'arch=i386'`
```

So I randomly tried rerunning `r CMD INSTALL RPostgreSQL_0.1-7.tar.gz`, which again seemed to install fine, but then I get a slightly different error when I call `library(RPostgreSQL)`:

```
'RPostgreSQL' is not a valid installed package
```

Any idea what's wrong? Is the package simply not supported in the latest version of R, so that I should downgrade my version of R (I guess, by uninstalling my current version and finding an older one?) if I want to use it?

Comment: which version of OS X are you running. On 10.7 I was able to download the source from the google code repo and build it using `install.packages(gzipped_source_path, repos = NULL, type="source")` I had xcode installed before installing, naturally. I didn't expect it to be that easy, and I'm not sure why I was able to build it when others have lots of troubles. Quirk of 10.7 maybe?

Comment: @JD Long: I'm running on 10.6.6, so that might be it. (Or maybe it's because of the R version? Not sure if you're running 2.13.1 as well.) Anyways, I ended up switching to RpgSQL instead, which seems to work fine =).

Answer (score 3):

The package is not building on CRAN. See the [CRAN page for details](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RPostgreSQL/index.html), which indicates that the MacOS X binary is not available. The package is failing to install. Here is the install log:

```
* installing *source* package 'RPostgreSQL' ...
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for pg_config... no
configure: checking for PostgreSQL header files
configure: Checking include /usr/include.
configure: Checking include /usr/include/pgsql.
configure: Checking include /usr/include/postgresql.
configure: Checking include /usr/local/include.
configure: Checking include /usr/local/include/pgsql.
configure: Checking include /usr/local/include/postgresql.
configure: Checking include /usr/local/pgsql/include.
configure: Checking include /usr/local/postgresql/include.
configure: Checking include /opt/include.
configure: Checking include /opt/include/pgsql.
configure: Checking include /opt/include/postgresql.
configure: Checking include /opt/local/include.
configure: Checking include /opt/local/include/postgresql.
configure: Checking include /opt/local/include/postgresql84.
configure: Checking include /sw/opt/postgresql-8.4/include.
configure: Checking include /Library/PostgresPlus/8.4SS/include.
configure: Checking include /sw/include/postgresql.
configure: Checking lib /usr/lib.
configure: Checking lib /usr/lib/pgsql.
configure: Checking lib /usr/lib/postgresql.
configure: Checking lib /usr/local/lib.
configure: Checking lib /usr/local/lib/pgsql.
configure: Checking lib /usr/local/lib/postgresql.
configure: Checking lib /usr/local/pgsql/lib.
configure: Checking lib /usr/local/postgresql/lib.
configure: Checking lib /opt/lib.
configure: Checking lib /opt/lib/pgsql.
configure: Checking lib /opt/lib/postgresql.
configure: Checking lib /opt/local/lib.
configure: Checking lib /opt/local/lib/postgresql.
configure: Checking lib /opt/local/lib/postgresql84.
configure: Checking lib /sw/opt/postgresql-8.4/lib.
configure: Checking lib /Library/PostgresPlus/8.4SS/lib.
configure: Checking lib /sw/lib.
checking for "/libpq-fe.h"... no
configure: error: File libpq-fe.h not in ; installation may be broken.
ERROR: configuration failed for package 'RPostgreSQL'
* removing '/Volumes/Tiger/Builds/Rdev-web/QA/Simon/packages/leopard-universal/results/2.13/RPostgreSQL.Rcheck/RPostgreSQL'
```

You should contact the package maintainer for further information.

Answer (score 3):

The [RPostgreSQL repo on Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/rpostgresql/) has clear documentation on [installing RPostgreSQL on Mac OS X](http://code.google.com/p/rpostgresql/wiki/MacOSXInstallFinkPostgresql), I suggest you start there.

Neil also tries to keep those up to date, so if this for whatever reason fails for you, you can always come to the [Google Groups mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#!forum/rpostgresql-dev).

Comment: You could also post to r-sig-Mac mailing list if the link above does not help.

Comment: I tried following that documentation, but now I get a different error (about loading `RPostgreSQL.so`), so I posted my question to the mailing list at https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#!topic/rpostgresql-dev/EzyH3B1wJes.

Comment: Good approach, with luck Neil can help you. I don't have an OS X box myself.